# How to convert string to utf-8 in swift ?

Tags: character-encoding, swift3, utf

I was send data with socket. But some character didn't convert utf8. 
I use this code when sending data

```
let message:String = self._messagesQueue[0]
let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { self.outputStream?.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
```

some character which "ş","ğ","ü" are displaying as "Å" 
How to fix it this text ?

Comment: Maybe try using `unicode` instead of `utf8`...

Comment: Your code is ok. It writes proper UTF-8 data. If there is a problem, it's on the receipient side.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper: That question is about NSAttributedString, I don't think it is related to this problem.

Comment: You are right. The problem was on the recipient side. Thank you @Codo